# Texstudio macro to convert subsection-level headers to titlecase

Tags: macros, texstudio

I want to write a Texstudio macro (script) that scans the entire `.tex` file and converts text inside all `\subsection{}` directives to titlecase.

```
\subsection{this is the title of this subsection}
```

to

```
\subsection{This Is the Title of This Subsection}
```

I am trying this kind of scripting for the first time.

Comment: This is not really on topic here. Also, there's no way to do this with a regex if you want *some* words (like articles and prepositions) not to be upper cased.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think the question is not clear enough and the OP just wants something like that in my answer...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting a bit, since the query doesn't appear to be TeXstudio-specific.

Comment: @Mico TeXstudio tag is relevant, I believe. TeXstudio has a built in function to change the selected text to Titlecase, so OP is asking how to invoke this using a TeXstudio user script.

Comment: @Troy - Thanks! I hadn't been aware of this TeXstudio function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my earlier comment, TeXstudio has an in-built "Convert to Titlecase" functionality under `Edit -> Text Operations -> To Titlecase`, which means there is no need for (1) complicated 'hacking' using TeX, and (2) considering of specific 'use cases' for Titlecase as per the other answers.

[image: toolbar invoking]

We can call this function in a TXS user macro, which was what I believe the OP was (originally) looking for.

> #### Disclaimer:
>
> I don't claim that the script below is well-polished and suitable for all use cases (it isn't!). I am also unsure of the exact workings of the `app.editTextToTitlecaseSmart()` function, but from what I have tested so far, it seems to work well, even with acronyms in the subsection title (cf. Example 1). 
>   Some information on titlecasing is provided by the TXS manual here: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION15
>
> The following script was tested in TXS 2.12.6. As with all macros in TXS though, the function names (i.e., `app.editTextToTitlecaseSmart()` et al.) are liable to change by the developers in the future, so the macro shown below *may not work* for future versions of TXS (>2.12.6).
>
> #### Notes on use:
>
> - Ensure that the `\subsection{...}` commands occupy their own lines as per my examples below. The only exception I would imagine is placing `\label{..}` after the `\subsection` call (cf. Example 1).
> - I assume you want the short titles for the subsection (if present) to be converted to titlecase as well. (cf. Example 2).
> - Please always **double check** if the conversion is done correctly by the user macro after invoking it.
>     The code provides a "Script Report" in a pop-up dialog window so that you can review what has been changed -- the *line number* and the *titles* that have been converted to title case.
>
>   If you have confidence in my code (!!) and want to disable the Script Report pop-up, then you can just comment/delete the last line of the code: `information(str);`.
> - A potential disadvantage of this method is that you will be unable to create exceptions for the titlecasing (I think), since it is all done by the `app.editTextToTitlecaseSmart` internal function.

## User script for "Automatic Conversion of Subsection Headers to Titlecase"

### Setting the macro

1. From the main toolbar, go to `Macros -> Edit Macros`.
2. Click `Add +` on the bottom left corner of the pop-up window to add a new user script.
3. Paste the following in the large box that says `LaTeX content` on the right side of the pop-up window:

   ```
   %SCRIPT
   /*  Note: Comment/Delete the last (optional) line if you 
       do not want the script report.
   */

   var tl = editor.document().textLines();
   var regEx = /\\subsection(\[.*\])*(\{((?!\\label).)*\})/;
   var str = "Script Report:\n\n";
   var match, scope, matchTC;

   function titlecase(c){
       editor.setCursor(c);
       app.editTextToTitlecaseSmart();
   }

   for (var i=0;i<tl.length;i++){
       match = regEx.exec(tl[i]);
       scope = editor.document().cursor(i, 0, i);
       // Titlecase the short titles [...]
       if (match && match[1]){
           editor.search(match[1], scope, titlecase)
           matchTC = cursor.selectedText();
           str += 'L' + (i+1).toString() + ' :: ' + matchTC + '\n';
       }
       // Titlecase the long titles {...}
       if (match && match[2]){
           editor.search(match[2], scope, titlecase)
           matchTC = cursor.selectedText();
           str += 'L' + (i+1).toString() + ' :: ' + matchTC + '\n';
       }
   }
   editor.selectNothing();
   information(str) // optional
   ```

[image: pasting]

### Testing the macro

**Some test cases:**

These are the examples that I tested with.

```
% Example 1: With label at the end + Acronyms not affected
\subsection{this should be in titlecase: NASA in a nutshell}\label{subsec:title}

% Example 2: Short titles also to be title-cased
\subsection[short titles]{capitalized every word except of the not needed in such cases}
\label{LabelOnANewLine}

% Example 3: Smart title-casing
\subsection{you can't {{{{escape}}}} 2!!}

% Example 4: Non-examples
\chapter{not this one}
\section{not this one too}
Normal text should not get affected as well.

% Example 5: Obscure example in a verbatim environment...
\verb|\subsection[the last example]{The last example in a long time...}|
```

**Gif:**

[image: gif working]

Comment: Thank you very much Troy. This is the exact script I was looking for.

Comment: @sar1729 You're welcome :) Let me know if you face any issues with this. I havent tested this extensively yet.

Comment: How did you find the callback used by texstudio's internal option for converting to titlecase. I do not see it under app object list in the link you provided.

Comment: Run the Introspection macro (found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#introspection)) for `app`. i.e., `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(app)`. It lists all possible functions for `app` in TXS. You can do the same for `editor`, `cursor` etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited According to @Mico's request**

Here is an answer **Old:(but I don't know if)** **New:(that I know)** it works in TeXstudio:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\MFUnocap{a} %We have to give the words we don't want to be automatically capitalized
\MFUnocap{non}
\MFUnocap{be}
\MFUnocap{of}
\MFUnocap{the}
\MFUnocap{in}
\MFUnocap{for}
\MFUnocap{etc}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldsubsection*{\capitalisewords{#2}}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{%
\oldsubsection*{\capitalisewords{#1}}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldsubsection[\capitalisewords{#1}]{\capitalisewords{#2}}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldsubsection{\capitalisewords{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\tableofcontents
   \section{test a non capitalized title}
   \lipsum[1-2]
   \subsection{this will be a capitalized simple subsection title}
   \lipsum[1-5]
   \section{non capitalized}
   \lipsum[1]
   \subsection[a capitalized toc and header title for now]{Capitalized every  word except of the not needed in such cases}
   \lipsum[1-11]
   \subsection*{a capitalized title}
   \lipsum[1-3]
   \subsection{capitalized a last title etc}
   \lipsum
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

You have to add `msfirstuc` package and include the lines after `\usepackage{lipsum}` and before `\begin{document}`.

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It was an old answer of mine from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378568/120578 that changed for subsection and without koma-script.

**Edit: PS(to ignore as @AlanMunn mentioned): If can not imported to TeXStudio feel free to ask me to delete it.**

Comment: TeXStudio is an editor, so I assume this will work. But I think the OP wants to change the source code directly. :) But this is certainly one way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn... Every time I hear TeXStudio I thinking MikTeX... lol (editing)...

Comment: I just noticed I have an answer to that question too. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn... You don't have an answer there... You have **the** answer... :P

Comment: Is there a (hopefully not too complicated) way to make this approach work if there's an optional argument to `\subsection`, i.e., for something like `\subsection[hello there][hello world]`? A separate concern: "titlecase" doesn't mean "capitalize the first letter of every single word" in the scope of `\subsection`. With "titlecase", short words such as "a", "the", "of" and "in" should be left in lowercase.

Comment: @Mico Edited. 2.Just added manually the words that I dont wont to be capitalized. 1. I had just a forgoten unclosed and unneeded if. (I suppose that you mean `\subsection[hello there]{hello world}` but there was no really problem with that... I thought about adding subsection with star and optional that changes the header... but didn't...  have done it on other post)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It first upper-cases the lowercase letters at the start of all words in both the mandatory argument and the optional argument (if present) of `\subsection`. It then makes exceptions for the words "the", "of", and "a".

The only input requirement is that the string `\subsection`, its optional argument in square brackets (if present), and its mandatory argument in curly braces all be on one line -- no line breaks allowed. I trust this isn't a binding constraint.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{luacode} 
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function my_upper ( z )
   -- First, uppercase all starting lowercase letters ('%l' in Lua jargon)
   -- "starting": %l is preceded by whitespace, {, or [
   z = z:gsub ( "[%s{%[]%l" , string.upper )
   -- Next, undo upper-casing for "of", "the" and "a"
   z = z:gsub ( " Of " , string.lower ) 
   z = z:gsub ( " The ", string.lower )
   z = z:gsub ( " A "  ,  string.lower )
   return z
end
function do_subsec ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "\\subsection%s*%b[]%s*%b{}", my_upper )
   s = s:gsub ( "\\subsection%s*%b{}", my_upper )
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", do_subsec, "do_subsec" )}}

\begin{document}
\section{this is the title of a section}
\subsection{this is the title of a subsection}
\subsubsection{this is the title of a subsubsection}
\bfseries hello world
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `titlecaps` package can help here.  Additionally, it allows you to designate lowercase words that are screened in the arguments (using `\Addlcwords{}`), and automatically filters out punctuation when deciding what to capitalize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps,lipsum}
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@ifstar{\subsectionstar}{\subsectionnostar}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\subsectionstar[2][]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\svsubsection*{\titlecap{#2}}\else
  \svsubsection*[\titlecap{#1}]{\titlecap{#2}}\fi}
\newcommand\subsectionnostar[2][]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\svsubsection{\titlecap{#2}}\else
  \svsubsection[\titlecap{#1}]{\titlecap{#2}}\fi}
\Addlcwords{a, for, of, etc, the}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
   \section{test a non capitalized title}
   \lipsum[4]

   \subsection{this will be a capitalized simple subsection title}
   \lipsum[4]

   \section{non capitalized}
   \lipsum[4]

   \subsection[a capitalized toc and header title for now]{Capitalized every  word except of the not needed in such cases}
   \lipsum[4]
   \subsection*{a capitalized title}
   \lipsum[4]
   \subsection{capitalized a last title etc}
   \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked for a macro script to convert the subsection into **titlecase**, you can try this script:

```
%SCRIPT
matches = triggerMatches;
title = matches[matches.length-1];
words=title.split(' ');
cursor.eraseLine();
editor.write("\\subsection{}");
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.Left);
editor.insertText(words[0][0].toUpperCase()+ words[0].substr(1).toLowerCase()+" ");
for (i=1; i<words.length-1; i++) {
if([";",":"].indexOf(words[i-1].slice(-1))>=0){
editor.insertText(words[i][0].toUpperCase()
+ words[i].substr(1).toLowerCase()+" ")
}
else{
if (["amid", "mid", "apud", "as", "at", "on", "atop", "bar", "but", "by", 
"chez", "down", "for", "from", "in", "into", "less", "like", "near", 
"of", "off", "on", "onto", "out", "over", "pace", "past", "per", 
"post", "pre", "pro", "qua", "sans", "sauf", "than", "thru", "to",  
"til", "up", "upon", " pon", "vs.", "via", "vice", "with", "w/", 
"w/i", "w/o", "for", "and", "nor", "but", "or", "yet", "so", "a", 
"an", "the", "some", "to"].indexOf(words[i].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
editor.insertText(words[i][0].toLowerCase()
+ words[i].substr(1).toLowerCase()+" ");
}
else {
editor.insertText(words[i][0].toUpperCase()
+ words[i].substr(1).toLowerCase()+" ");
}
}
}
editor.insertText(words[words.length-1][0].toUpperCase()+ words[words.length-1].substr(1).toLowerCase());
```

You can add a triger, in my case the triger is:

```
(?<=\\subsection\{([^}]*)\})[t]
```

So when you just type the letter "t" after the braces of any subsection, it will change to titlecase.

Comment: @Troy Now you can check the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using TeX primitives:

```
% \def\subsection{{\bf#1}\par} %< use this if you are not using LaTeX (like me)  

% code from OPmac:
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\isinlist#1#2#3{\begingroup \long\def\tmp##1#2##2\end{\def\tmp{##2}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \endgroup \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname \else
                  \endgroup \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname \fi}%
   \expandafter\tmp#1\endlistsep#2\end
}

\let\ssecOri=\subsection
\def\subsection#1{\def\tmp{}\docapA#1 {} \expandafter\ssecOri\expandafter{\tmp}}
\def\docapA#1#2 {%
   \ifx^#1^\else
      \ifx\tmp\empty\else \addto\tmp{ }\fi
      \isinlist\exceptions{,#1#2,}\iftrue 
         \addto\tmp{#1#2}%
      \else
         \uppercase{\addto\tmp{#1}}\addto\tmp{#2}%
      \fi
   \expandafter\docapA\fi
}
\def\exceptions{,a,non,be,of,the,in,for,etc,}

% test:
\subsection{this will be a capitalized simple subsection title}

\bye
```